# How to bind text formatted with converter?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have two lists of keywords and I have to display a string with uncommon words in white and common words in orange.

I made a converter to do this. At the beginning, I try to make a SpannableString to return my string with some attributes for the color, but the binding seemed to be complex, so I tred to put some html code in my string and return an ISpanned string instead.

It works but nothing ever gets displayed, I don't understand why...

To make my binding I use the following code:

```
            set.Bind(poiDisplayer).For(s=>s.Text).To(vm => vm.CurrentMember.Member.PostedBy.Interests).WithConversion(new CommonPOIConverter(ViewModel.CurrentMember.Member.Interests)).WithFallback(new List<Interests>());
```

And the converter is like this:

```
protected override ISpanned Convert(List<Interests> value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string finalString = ""; string tmpString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Count; i++)
        {
            tmpString = "";
            foreach (var item in myInterestes)
            {
                if (item.Name == value[i].Name)
                {
                    tmpString += "<font color=\"orange>\"#" + value[i].Name + "</> ";
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (tmpString.Length == 0)
                tmpString += "<font color=\"white>\"#" + value[i].Name + "</> ";
            finalString += tmpString;
        }
        return Html.FromHtml(finalString);
    }
```

Any idea on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Considering your `MvxValueConverter` works as expected, you need to bind your value to the `TextFormatted` property instead of `Text`, like this:

```
set.Bind(poiDisplayer).For(s=>s.TextFormatted).To(vm => vm.CurrentMember.Member.PostedBy.Interests).WithConversion(new CommonPOIConverter(ViewModel.CurrentMember.Member.Interests)).WithFallback(new List<Interests>());
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I try with s.TextFormatted, it "works", I have no error or warning but nothing displayed... I have Nothing in the log about the binding

Comment: [This](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/MvvmCross/Binding/Droid/Target/MvxTextViewTextFormattedTargetBinding.cs) is the class used in this binding. Try checking it to see if you're doing everything right